# Создание объекта класса - имя класса в переменной string

Tags: php

Мне нужно создать объект класса, имя которого записано в переменной $string. Как это сделать.

```
new $string;
```

не получается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во первых, если не изменяет память - синтаксис создания экземпляра класса следующий:

```
$a = new Class();
```

А у вас получается:

```
$a = new Class;
```

А во-вторых - где у вас класс $string находится? Если в том же файле - то хорошо, а если в другом, то надо как бы

```
require_once($script);
```

Ну и следовательно код должен быть таким:

```
require_once($script);
$a = new $className();
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.