# Как извлечь из переменной имя класса и создать объект?

Tags: php

В переменной хранится имя класса в виде строки:

```
$classname=‘auto’;
```

Как создать объект типа:

```
$obj= new $classname; //не работает
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание объекта класса - имя класса в переменной string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/186678/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$obj= new $classname();
```

Answer (score 0):

Что вообще значит создать экземпляр класса из названия переменной. Во-первых, класс должен быть сначала определён, вами или не вами. Во-вторых, если вы хотите создавать экземпляр класса из строки, нужно проверить является ли содержимое строки названием существующего класса:

```
if ($classname="auto") {
        $obj = new auto();
}
```

Возможно, если вы расскажете, что вам нужно, я смогу помочь, потому что ваша реализация не имеет никакого смысла так как, возможно, вы не совсем понимаете структуру ООП

Comment: Михаил, все классы уже созданы и подключены. В переменной хранится название класса для продукта, полученное из бд. Т.е. мы изначально не знаем, что это auto либо bicycle. Вот нужно создать объект из соответствующего класса. Но ваше решение слишком громоздко, т.к. классов может быть десятки

Comment: А решение Streletz у вас заработало?